# Find a function where the mode is the minimum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization

Let $a_i\in\Bbb R$ some collection of data points where $0\le i\le n$. Define the function $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n(x-a_i)^2$$
It is clear that the minimum value of $f$ occurs when $x$ is the mean of $a_i$. Similarly a function $$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n|x-a_i|$$ has a minimum value when $x$ is the median. Which leads me to my question.

**Can a similar function be constructed for the mode?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $\delta : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\delta(x,y)$ equals $0$ when $x = y$ and equals $1$ otherwise. Then

$$
h(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \delta(x,a_i)
$$

will return a minimum value when $x$ is the mode of the $a_i$.

It's interesting to note that $(x-y)^2$, $|x-y|$, and $\delta(x,y)$ are all valid metrics over $\mathbb{R}$. Really shows how the mean, mode, and median all measure the 'average' element in different ways!

Comment: Would you know if one can choose a continuous $\delta$?

Comment: Since the mode is a very not continuous statistic my gut reaction is no. I think it may be possible to prove that this is not possible with any metric, at least.